# Secure Google Cloud Storage bucket with credentials

Tags: security, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

I would like to secure a Google Cloud Storage bucket with credentials (something like htaccess on Apache). The users who need to access to a specific GCS bucket are external to the company. What would be the recommended way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Authentication with Cloud Storage APIs

The [link Mike shared](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication) talks more about how you can authenticate with the Cloud Storage API. You have 2 main choices - using the [User Account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#user_accounts) or using [Service account credentials](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication#service_accounts).

Once you have figured out what kind of authentication the users will be using, you can look at how to control access to the buckets and objects stored within the buckets.

Cloud storage provides 2 main ways to control access - IAM roles and ACLs.

### IAM roles

I would recommend going over the [`IAM permissions`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-permissions) and the [`IAM roles`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-roles) available for Cloud Storage. These provide control at project and bucket level.

### Access Control Lists (ACLs)

In addition, you can use [ACLs to control permissions at the object level within the bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/lists).

Comment: I choose to do it using service account credentials as an automated program will get access to the data.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for Google Cloud Storage authentication is at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication